# Dispatch an event on resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my main class I have a throttled on resize method.

How can I make this trigger an event that can be listened for in any classes in my app, so they can they react if necessary?

So for example, only on my news page do I load my news class:

```
if(document.getElementById('news') !== null) {
        this.news = new app.News();
}
```

Is there a way in my news class to listen for an event triggered by a resize method in my main class? Also how would I dispatch the event?

```
$(window).on('resize', Foundation.utils.throttle(function(e){
    //dispatch event
}, 300));
```

Comment: As you said, you [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) it

Comment: might also want to check out mutation observers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Or you write a custom event and listen for it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events